# What causes a linear taper slide pot to develop dead spots?

Tags: potentiometer

new here and judging from the kinds of questions being asked mine is probably too simple.

But, I have an old turntable that doesn't seem to recognise the tap that is in the central position on the pitch controller and therefore wont allow me to change the speed correctly.

It works if I push the slider backwards ie -2% to -10% pitch, but if I move it forwards it doesnt recognise the movement until it gets to around plus 6% and then it speeds up instantly.

A replacement part is no longer available either from the manufacturer (Numark) or apparently aftermarket.

Can I apply a carbon based paint to the carbon tracks inside or are there any other methods of repair you can advise please?

Thanks Jim

Comment: Do you have a picture of the actual slider pot? It might be possible to identify what replacement part you'll need. It could be a very standard potentiometer.

Answer (score 1):

Dead spots in pots are generally caused by buildup of less conductive contaminants on the surfaces contacted by the slider.  They can often be removed with a red pencil eraser, although disassembly and reassembly may be more difficult than the removal itself.  In this case, it's also possible the contacting surface has been eroded, since this is the range the pot is used in the vast majority of the time.

From your description, it sounds like you're seeing some hysteresis between two settings.  This could be a different phenomenon, or it could be an artifact of the other circuitry.

Even though the pot itself is discontinued, it may be possible to find a replacement if you can find the specifications of the part.  Of particular importance is the power dissipation, which could require specialty parts if over 1W.

Answer (score 0):

It's just wear and since you spend the most time near the central position so that gets scraped the most so that's where the wear develops first. If you have room to add a resistor on one side you can move your center adjust to somewhere else on the pot with less wear.